# Angular make an api call async and use the result

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to make an API call

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.function1()
}

function1(){
  this.userService.getUser()
  .then((data) => {
   this.user = data.user
   this.userM = data.userM
// here problem: If I make a console.log(this.userM) it result at the beginning empty
   if(this.userM.length > 0 ) {
       console.log("goInside")}
   else {
    console.log("doesn't enter")
     //it enters always there
   }
  }
}
```

in my service:

```
async getUser(): Promise<any>{
  let user: any = []
  let userM: any = []
  //.... operation to populate
  return {user, userM}
}
```

When I make an api call I would to use the this.userM array to make some operations. But it results always empty at the beginning, but it doens't enter anymore in if. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `rxjs`, try using an `Observable` instead:

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';

getUsers(): Observable<any> {
  let user: any = []
  let userM: any = []
  //.... operation to populate

  return of({user, userM});
}
```

And then, within your component:

```js
ngOnInit(){
  this.function1()
}

function1(){
  this.userService.getUser().subscribe((response) => {
    const { user, userM } = response;

    if (userM.length) console.log('There is data in it!')
    else console.log('No data found...');
  });
}
```

I suggest not using `Promises` in an `Angular` project unless necessary, you have at your disposal `rxjs` along with tons of useful operators for handling async calls/streams of data

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'm testing as you suggest, but in this way how can I check if the this.user or this.userM in if statement?